# Improving perfomance(speed) of exponent problem

Tags: python

I'm currently learning Python on repl.it and I have a problem with one of my work.

My code is supposed to:

1.**Input a given integer X**

2.**Find the greatest integer n where 2ⁿ is less than or equal to X.**

3.**Print the exponent value(n) and the result of the expression 2ⁿ.**

But my code fail as the machine insert too big number like 10^8+2. The program completely failed

Here is the piece of code that I'm working on:

```
X = int(input())
a = X//2
while a > -1:
  if (2**a) < =x:
    print(a)
    print(2**a)
    break
  else:
    a -= 1
```

Can anyone find me another solution to this problem, or improve the bit of code I'm working on by its runtime? It works with small number(less than 10^6) but otherwise the program freeze.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [NO taglines please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). / Find a better algorithm.

Comment: `a=int(X**(1.0/2.0))` would let you start closer to the right answer. Can you provide what input failed

Comment: Start with `a = int(math.log(X) / math.log(2)) + 1`, or something like that.

Comment: When it inputtoo big numbers, in this case it's 14321432

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, I can't refer to the "too big input" that you mention (since you didn't provide it), but as for the problem itself, it could be easier solved in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
a = int(np.log2(your_input))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see is that in you code

```
if (2**a) < =x:
    print(a)
    print(2**a)
```

you calculate the value of `2**a` twice. A good start could be to save the value of `2**a` into a variable. However, since you are only doing powers of 2 you could also take a look at bitwise operations. So instead of doing `a = X//2` you could also write

```
a= X >> 2
```

and instead of doing `2**a` write

```
temp = 1 << a
```

When working with powers of 2 it can be significantly faster to work with bitwise operations.

Answer (score 0):

I did it! (using some of your solutions of course)
This is my teachers code :

```
x = int(input())
n = 1
while 2 ** n <= x:
  n += 1
print(n - 1, 2 ** (n - 1))
```